# Convert Base class to Derived class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to convert Base class to derived class object. See below code, I am having the issue when I converting. It is basic thing, but struggling.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/Edit/{Id}")]
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
{

    List<ClassA> Data = Ctx.GetClassAFromId(Id);

    // Now Here I want convert ABC List<ClassA> to XyZ List<ClassA>
    //How to do that?
    return View(DataXYZ);
}
```

### Model generate by EF

```
namespace ABC
{

    public partial class ClassA
    {
           public string First_name { get; set; }
           public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Project model

```
namespace XYZ
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ClassAMetadata))]
    public partial class ClassA:ABC.ClassA
    {

    }   

    public class ClassAMetadata
    {
        [DisplayName(@"First Name")]
        [Required]
        public string First_name { get; set; }


        [DisplayName(@"Last Name")] 
        [Required]       
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How Can convert ABC.ClassA to XYZ.ClassA?

### Edit:

we are working on i18n project. So we need to display each text in different languages. But our EF project is in different Namespace and web project is in different Namespace. that is the reason I deriving from base class

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: Either use automapper, or write a constructor for XYZ.ClassA which takes an ABC.ClassA as a parameter, and assigns the fields from it appropriately.

Comment: You cannot simply 'convert' (typecast) it. You'll need to copy the properties. Which makes me wonder why you have 2 separate models like this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though their names are alike, they are completely different classes. It'd be just the same as if you called them `Foo` and `Bar`

You'll need a method that converts these objects. It takes a `Foo` object as parameter, then returns an equivalent `Bar` object

```
public Bar Foo_To_Bar(Foo myFoo)
{
    return new Bar() { Prop1 = myFoo.Prop1, Prop2 = myFoo.Prop2 };
}
```

Something like that. You'll probably also need a method that goes the other way around if you want to convert in both directions.

Note: If the classes have properties with the same name, I suggest you look into [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). It automates much of the boring work for you.

**Edit**
Apparently, your `Foo` inherits from `Bar`. That complicates things a bit more. I'll rework this answer when I get the time.

I don't see a use case for having your ViewModel (XYZ.ClassA) **derive from** your base entity (ABC.ClassA). Can you explain why this is needed? I think you're misusing inheritance here.

Generally speaking, you'd want your `XYZ.ClassA` to have a property of type `ABC.ClassA` (or any `IEnumerable<ABC.ClassA>` variation), not inherit from it.

Can you please confirm if this is an actual requirement, or can be part of the issue and is allowed to change if it fixes your problem?

Comment: They are not "completely different classes". One derives from the other (and yes, that usually means some properties with the same name).

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Come to think of it, it's an odd question. If both classes should be directly convertable to eachother, why would they inherit eachother? I'm trying to find a use case for this, but I'm drawing a blank. In OP's example, his derived class is actually his ViewModel. I'm... confused right now.

Comment: @Flater, we are working on i18n project. So we need to display each text in different languages. But our EF project is in different Namespace and web project is in different Namespace. that is the reason I deriving from base class.

Comment: Like I said, deriving is not what you want, you're misusing it. Think of your viewmodel as a "bundle of data". However, directly using your entities in your MVC application is dangerous as well. I suggest you change your current implementation to your base entity (ABC.ClassA), a DTO that is structurally similar (XYZ.ClassADTO), and then a Viewmodel (XYZ.MyFancyViewModel) that  has a **property** of type XYZ.ClassADTO (or an IEnumerable variation thereof).

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert `List<BaseClass>` to `List<DerivedClass>`

What you can do is used linq:

```
listABC.Cast<XYZ.ClassA>.ToList()
```

But lookout - it is `O(n)` procedure

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - based on the fact that one object is inherited from the other, see [C#/.NET Little Wonders: Use Cast() and OfType() to Change Sequence Type](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/07/c.net-little-wonders-use-cast-and-typeof-to-change-sequence.aspx)

---

Couple of options:

1.

```
namespace ABC
{

    public partial class ClassA
    {
           public ClassA(XYZ.ClassA classToConvert)
           {
             this.First_name = classToConvert.First_name,
             this.Last_Name = classToConvert.Last_Name
           }

           public string First_name { get; set; }
           public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Use it singularly:

```
 var newClassA = new ABC.ClassA((XYZ.ClassA)classA)
```

Do it in a list:

```
 List<ABC.ClassA> newClassAList = classAList.Select(p => new ABC.ClassA((XYZ.ClassA)p).ToList();
```

Or do it in a list without the above constructor and using an object initaliser

```
 List<ABC.ClassA> newClassAList = classAList.Select(p => new ABC.ClassA{First_name = p.First_name, Last_Name = p.Last_Name}.ToList();
```

1. As others have mentioned Use AutoMapper.

   - Use Nuget and add AutoMapper to your project (and some initalisation code)
   - Create your Map:

     ```
     Mapper.CreateMap<XYZ.ClassA, ABC.ClassA>();
     ```
   - Map your objects:

     ```
     var myABCClassA= Mapper.Map<XYZ.ClassA, ABC.ClassA>(myXYZClassA);
     ```
   - As long as your property names on both classes match thats all the code you need

Answer (score 0):

I created this today

```
public static void Map<T1, T2>(this T1 obj1, T2 obj2) where T1 : class where T2 : class
{
    IEnumerable<(PropertyInfo p1, PropertyInfo p2)> properties = typeof(T1).GetProperties()
        .Join(typeof(T2).GetProperties(), o => o.Name, t => t.Name, (o, t) => (o, t));
    foreach((PropertyInfo p1, PropertyInfo p2) in properties)
    {
        if (p1.CanWrite && p1.PropertyType == p2.PropertyType)
        {
            p1.SetValue(obj1, p2.GetValue(obj2));
        }
    }
}
```